# Templates with boost::bind?

Tags: c++, boost, bind

I'm looking for functionality similar to the following:

```
template<typename T, boost::function<T* (HandleId)> resolveFunc>
class Handle
{
public:
   T* resolve() const
   {
      return resolveFunc(_handleId);
   }

private:
   HandleId _handleId;
};
```

I can't seem to find a way of doing this. It's important that sizeof(Handle) == sizeof(HandleId), so I can't store the function as a member..

Can anyone help? :)

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to have non-type parameter of boost::function, only integral, ptr and refs having external linkage are allowed ...

Comment: Could you elaborate? Naturally this approach can never work as `resolveFunc` is an instance of a user defined type. If you want to use `boost::function<>` then it can never be solved compile time in the way you want. Perhaps it's better if you give some more background on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis your information is outdated :) C++11 allows internal linkage functions.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how much information is encoded by the `resolveFunc`.

If there are, say, only 5 possible functions, then you can encode that as 5 ordinary functions, problem solved.

If there is much more information then this is classic case of trying to encode run time information at compile time; that's doomed to failure. One way to solve the technical problem is then to use a static map, mapping from handles to pointers. But: in this case it's very likely that the real problem is at the design level, so doing the technical would be unwise. Even though it works, technically.

Comment: Thanks - I need a templated handle class which represents a reference to some object. It also needs to be able to look up and return the object using an external function. I'm not sure how to go about this?